# override filter in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-4

Is there a way to override a filter in Laravel 4?

I have a package installed which has a filter checking for user id's in the URL and we've modified the routes so it doesn't have any ID's in it.  However the package filter explicitly checks for it

```
// we need to determine if a non admin user                                  
// is trying to access their own account.                                    
$userId = Route::input('id');
```

I can get around it by extending the controller which is using the filter, but it seems like more of a headache when I'd really like to make a small tweak and be done.

Comment: What kind of filter, post it please.